# Show that if $x(x-(2a)^2)>0$, it follows that $|x-(a)^2|>a^2$

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

I have to prove or show that for $a \in\mathbb{R}$ if $x(x-(2a)^2)>0$, it follows that $|x-(a)^2|>a^2$ is true or not. I think it is true, as $x-(2a)^2$ has to be either bigger or as smaller than $0$, and it's also the case in the following situation but I'm not sure if there would be more cases when $x>0$ and $x<0$ is and therefore could be shown that it's false. I would be happy if you could tell me if my way is true or not.

I assumed that $x$ $\neq$ 0 and $x-(2a)^2$ $\neq$ 0.
Then I calculated the inequality of $|x-(a)^2|>a^2$.
$|x-(a)^2|>0$ and $|x-(a)^2|<0$.
Then I showed that this preposition is true, as I assumed that $x-(2a)^2$ $\neq$ 0

Comment: What is $a$? Is it $a \in \mathbb{R}$ or just $a \ge 0$? Moreover, you should post your work or probably this question will be closed.

Comment: Sorry I forgot, a is a member of the set of real numbers, ∈ℝ

Comment: Ok, I edited your question accordingly. You can edit it yourself adding what you tried.

Comment: The condition $|x - a^2| > a^2$ is equivalent to $x > 2a^2$ or $x < 0$. From here it is obvious that the conclusion is true.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x(x-4a^2)>0$.

If $x>0$, $x - 4a^2>0$. Thus $x - 2a^2 > 2a^2 \ge 0$, this is, $x-a^2 > a^2 \ge 0$. Since $x - a^2 > 0$, $|x - a^2| = x - a^2$ and $|x - a^2| > a^2$.

If $x < 0$, $-x > 0$. Thus $a^2 - x > a^2 \ge 0$. Since $a^2 - x > 0$, $|a^2 - x| = a^2 - x$, but $|a^2 - x| = |x - a^2|$ and $|x - a^2| > a^2$.

Comment: Note that what @ムータンーオ just said was used.